# How to make racer map?

Tags: xna, c#, 3d

Hi everyone does 3D racer games use heightmap to build tracks or programmers just use easier solution ? I need to build only track space(road) without fill all hectares with trinagels and more important i need to raise smooth ascents on this tracks

i aksing for some tips not for completle solution of course.

Answer (score 3):

Well typically the map is modeled in 3D with everything included, and perhaps a spline of the race track. For things like grassy parts that slow down the car/whatever, you can look at the materials under the car to decide how to affect physics. I can't see heightmaps being used for racing games. Shawn Hargreaves (who was on the XNA team) also worked on Moto GP. Here are two articles on how some of the design was done in that game:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/06/03/motogp-curved-surfaces.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/12/30/motogp-ai-coordinate-systems.aspx

(for all of his articles on MotoGP: http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html#MotoGP)